# SammyJS not working with Django

Tags: javascript, django, sammy.js

I am using KnockoutJS with SammyJS for client-side templating, and Django framework
In the topbar of my application, there is a dropdown menu for user logout. This is the code for it -

```
<div class="pull-right user">
    <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <p><span id="topbar_first_name"></span></p> 
        <b class="caret"></b>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="{% url 'user:logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </a>
</div>
```

Before I started using SammyJS, the logout link worked. But now, only the url of the browser changes to '`http://localhost:8000/user/logout/`' ( this is the correct url of the link ). Only after reloading the page, the user is able to logout.

In my JS file, this is the only function of Sammy -

```
Sammy(function() {
    this.get('#:folder', function() {
        self.chosenFolderId(this.params.folder);
        $.get('/tasks/get', { folder: this.params.folder }, function(data) {
            self.tasks_list(data);
        });
    });

    this.get('', function() {
        this.app.runRoute('get', '#Active')
    });
}).run();
```

I tried changing the 'href' to an external link ( like 'www.stackoverflow.com' ). After this, the url of the browser changes to '`http://localhost:8000/www.stackoverflow.com`' but it doesn't work. How to remove this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
this.get('', function() {
    this.app.runRoute('get', '#Active')
});
```

is messing your links. This tells SammyJS to intercept all links. What are you trying to achieve with this? What I would do is :

```
Sammy(function() {
   this.get('#:folder', function() {
       self.chosenFolderId(this.params.folder);
      $.get('/tasks/get', { folder: this.params.folder }, function(data) {
        self.tasks_list(data);
       });
    });

}).run('#Active');
```

Comment: the line - " this.get('', ... " was shown in KnockoutJS tutorial to switch to 'Active' folder even when no hash was specified. I've updated my Sammy function, and now the logout link works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SammyJS is interecepting your call I think. 
You have two choices, either you can add a route in SammyJS so that it redirects to the correct location:

```
this.get('/user/logout', function() {
    location.assign('/user/logout');
});
```

... or, directly write a simple function for bypassing SammyJs for such cases:

```
function goToExternaLink(url) {
   window.location = url;
}
```

and then call this function from your `a` tag with an `onclick`, like this:

```
<a tabindex="-1" onclick="goToExternalLink('{% url 'user:logout' %}')">Logout</a>
```

But that `onclick` is not very pretty...

Comment: The second method works.
The first one does the same thing - changes url of page to /user/logout but does not 'execute' it. Any way to disable Sammy for the clicks originating from a particular div ( in this case - the topbar ) ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to disable SammyJS for a particular DIV. Maybe you could try with location.assign(url). I think this should work (I edited my first code excerpt)